# Why is netbeans IDE exit unexpectedly when launched

Tags: netbeans, launcher

I just installed Netbeans 7.1.2 on a system. It all installed well. However, when I try loading the IDE it starts briefly and only to exit after a while at the usual "Loading Cached Objects". Any form of help to tackle this will be appreciated.

The Output from the console :

```
    The launcher has determined that the parent process has a 
    console and will reuse it for its own console output:

    Closing the console will result in termination of the running program
    Use '--console supprress' to suppress console output
    Use  '--console new' to create a separate window
    Java HotSpot<TM> 64-Bit Server VM warning : ignoring option   

    PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0

    Java HotSpot<TM> 64-Bit Server VM warning : ignoring option 

    PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Then it terminates

Comment: Help can only be provided if you give us hints. E.g. you could start the IDE from command line and paste the log output the programm will write to the console before it crashes.

Comment: Thanks, it has been updated

Comment: Are you sure to be on a 64bit OS ?

Comment: Yes, it is on 64bit Windows 7 OS